# REST filter executes first part of filter

Tags: javascript, rest, filter, sharepoint-rest-api, filtermulivalue

I am trying to make a filter with REST, the code executes only the first part of the filter, here's my query:

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Data')/items?$orderby Created desc&$filter=(Category eq 'Students') and (Registered ne null)
```

However, it's getting all Students, whether registered or not. any help is appreciated.

Registered column is single line of text.

Comment: Did you try '' instead of null

Comment: Correct, An empty Single Line of Text is an empty string, not null

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, if you check the value of the column returned by sharepoint in developer tools, it will be null, not an empty string.

Comment: @MonicaJagani, please check my comment above.

Comment: I tried the multiple $filter, works fine on a  standard Tasks list with empty DueDates... but.. thats a Date field.. not a text field; but also returns *null* in the REST response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it by checking null values, you can do it by getting items where the column is gt 0, so your query would be like:

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Data')/items?$orderby Created desc&$filter=(Category eq 'Students') and (Registered gt 0)
```

This will check the length of the string added to the column, in this case > 0 would mean ne null.

Comment: it worked :) so with text fields i can not use null?

Comment: that's correct.